# How to allow spaces in a number format with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression:

```
(?:\d*\.)?\d+. (?:\d*\.)?\d+
```

which matches for `[any_number].[one_space][any_number]` like `23. 09`

I need this kind of `regex` to work for the following:

`[any_number][zero_or_more_spaces].[zero_or_more_spaces][any_number]` like - `23 .09` or `23. 09` or `23.09` or `23 . 09` or `23  .09` ..etc.

Comment: Your conditions are redundant, one condition is enough for all:`[any_number][zero_or_more_spaces].[zero_or_more_spaces][any_number]`

Comment: Yes @Identity1. Edited Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\d+\s*\.\s*\d+
```

**DESCRIPTION**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/rQ4eD6/1